# Django form - Calling is_valid() in a template

Tags: django, forms, validation

I'm using Django 1.5. I have a template with multiple forms: one driver has many cars (inline forms). I want to display a hint indicating which section contains errors.

The template:

```
{% if driver_form.is_bound and not driver_form.is_valid %}
    Please correct errors in the Driver Data.
{% endif %}
{% if car_form.is_bound and not car_form.is_valid %}
    Please correct errors in the Car Data.
{% endif %}
```

The problem is that if the first form is invalid, the second message pops up as well, even though the second form is valid. I also noticed that if I put `{{ car_form.is_valid }}` three times in a row, the first time it is empty, the next time (and following) it is `True`.

The original view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    driver_form = DriverModelForm(request.POST)
    car_form_set = CarInlineFormSet(request.POST)  # wrong: no instance passed
    if driver_form.is_valid():
        driver = driver_form.save(commit=False)
        car_form_set = CarInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=driver)
        if car_form_set.is_valid():
            driver.save()
            car_form_set.save()
else:
    driver_form = DriverModelForm()
    car_form_set = CarInlineFormset()
return render(request, 'template.html', {
    'driver_form': driver_form,
    'car_form_set': car_form_set
})
```

UPDATE:

It seems that for simplicity's sake I left out the details that actually caused the problem. Lesson learned.

1. There was a Javascript setting values on page load, while it only needed to be done on a dropdown change. It was hiding the erroneous values and causing the form to be valid next time around.
2. There is a dependency: `driver_form` is a model form, and `car_form_set` is an inline form set based on the instance that the `driver_form` is adding.

The problem was indeed in the view, as *seddonym* suggested: the `car_form_set` was not being initialized with an instance if the `driver_form` was invalid. So `is_valid()` was neither `True` nor `False`. Conclusion: using `is_valid()` in the template works just fine.

The fixed view:

```
driver = Driver()
if request.method == 'POST':
    driver_form = DriverModelForm(request.POST, instance=driver)
    if driver_form.is_valid():
        driver = driver_form.save(commit=False)
    car_form_set = CarInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=driver)
    if car_form_set.is_valid():
        driver.save()
        car_form_set.save()
else:
    driver_form = DriverModelForm(instance=driver)
    car_form_set = CarInlineFormset(instance=driver)
return render(request, 'template.html', {
    'driver_form': driver_form,
    'car_form_set': car_form_set
})
```

Comment: Its not good idea to do such things in template. BTW when you render the template, it will be using old data not the data being submitted by the user.

Comment: @Rohan Why should it be using old data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call form.is_valid, that will already have been called by the view.  Instead, check for errors:

```
{% if first_form.errors %}
    Please correct errors in the First Form.
{% endif %}
{% if second_form.errors %}
    Please correct errors in the Second Form.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If using function views you need to implicitly call .is_valid() yourself.

Comment: It's true, I'm assuming that code_assassin is correctly implementing the view.  @code_assassin, if this doesn't work then feel free to update your answer with the view you're using too.

Comment: The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) states that the form is validated the first time either you call `is_valid()` or access `errors`, and it only happens once, so there should be no difference.